# Bundle-NativeCode: header in MANIFEST file give "Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file pr.jar"

Tags: java, java-native-interface, osgi, jna, jmf

I was attempting to include natives libraries into a jar file. Though i found how it should be done, there something that is missing. This is the manifest file.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: ListMediaDevices

Name: library
URL: http://jspeex.sourceforge.net/
Library-Version: 0.9.7
Library-Name: JSpeex

Name: build
Build-Date: 10/05/2010 18:59
Built-With: Linux 2.6.32-21-generic amd64
Built-By: damencho

Bundle-NativeCode:
    lib/jnawtrenderer.dll;
    lib/jndirectshow.dll;
    lib/jnffmpeg.dll;
    lib/jng722.dll;
    lib/jnopus.dll;
    lib/jnportaudio.dll;
    lib/jnscreencapture.dll;
    lib/jnspeex.dll;
    lib/jnwincoreaudio.dll;
    osname=Win32;processor=x86
```

As per specification i do use UTF8 encoding and end the file with a new line. Some how loading the jar file

```
java -jar pr.jar give "Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file"
```

In order to replicate the issue, i remove the entire bundle header along with the lib parameters and added an arbitrary header "xyz:" it seems to give the same error, so i conclude, some where my implementation can't identify "Bundle-NativeCode:" Header.

Other information

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Library being used is libjitsi.jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use single spaces instead of tabs or multiple spaces in the `Bundle-NativeCode` header as the [JAR File Specification, Name-Value pairs and Sections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Name-Value_pairs_and_Sections) specifies:

```
header:            name : value
name:              alphanum *headerchar
value:             SPACE *otherchar newline *continuation
continuation:      SPACE *otherchar newline
```

Here is a sample manifest.mf snippet which works for me:

```
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Bundle-NativeCode: aaaaaaaaaaa.dll, bbbbbbbbbbb.dll, cccccccccc.dll, d
 ddddddddddddddd.dll, eeeeeeeeee.dll, ffffffff.dll, ggggggggggggggg.dl
 l, hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.dll, iiiiii.dll
```

Comment: If Stack overflow allowed multiple ups, i would have given you more :)

Comment: The Bundle-NativeCode header also needs to be part of the first section of the manifest before the first blank line). Also the manifest does not look like an OSGi bundle manifest. No Bundle-ManifestVersion or Bundle-SymbolicName headers...